# jquery mobile image is pixeleted

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have noticed that JQuery Mobile in phonegap is working fine for iphone . But when I run similar application on android especially Ldpi(320X240) it is not working properly.Images such as buttons are pixeleted. Any help on this is highly apperciated.

Thanks in adv

Comment: please add some code, your description of the problem is a good intro, but lacks in depth.

Answer (score 1):

In android apps you can provide multiple bitmaps for each screen density in `res/drawable-ldpi` `res/drawable-hdpi`, etc...

But it won't work here, because phonegap will load bitmap from asset folder. But you can do exactly as android does in your webpage using css3 media queries.

exemple:

- for a 100px image name it btn-mdpi.png,
- create a 75px image naming it btn-ldpi.png,
- create a 150px image naming it btn-hdpi.png,
- then create a 200px image naming it btn-xhdpi.png

here is the `<head>` of your webpage:

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
  <style>
    input {
        background: transparent url(btn-mdpi.png);
        height: 100px;
    }

    @media screen and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio:0.75) {
        input {
        background: transparent url(assets/btn-ldpi.png);
        height: 75px;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio:1.0) {
        input {
        background: transparent url(assets/btn-mdpi.png);
        height: 100px;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio:1.5) {
        input {
        background: transparent url(assets/btn-hdpi.png);
        height: 150px;
        }
    }
    @media screen and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio:2.0) {
        input {
        background: transparent url(assets/btn-xhpi.png);
        height: 200px;
        }
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

For each density, a different bitmap will be used matching the screen density. And good news it will also work for iphone 4+ and its retina display!

You can read this old romain nurik post to learn more about it: http://designbycode.tumblr.com/post/1127120282/pixel-perfect-android-web-ui